# Several Ajax add to cart forms on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have a page on a website with several products on the same page.

I am trying to get an Ajax add to cart to work for each one (each has it's own form), but cannot figure out how to differentiate between one product and the other without writing Jquery functions for each.

The script below works for one product on a page as the form has it's own ID, but when there are 20 products on one page, this does not work.

```
function update_cart(data, statusText, xhr, $form)
{
    if (data.success)
    {
        $("input[name=XID]").val(data.XID);
        $('.cart_total').html(data.cart_total); 
    }
    return true; 
}
var cart_form_options = {
    success: update_cart,
    dataType: 'json'
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#add_to_cart_submit").click(function(){

        $("#add_to_cart_form").ajaxForm(cart_form_options);
        $("#add_to_cart_form").submit(); 
    })
});
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you add your html too?  Then I can update my answer to include an example

Answer (score 0):

Give each product 'add to cart' button/form a unique attribute, like a product ID.  Then when the 'add to cart' button is clicked you can get that attribute to find out the exact product to add.

```
<form id="add_to_cart_form" productID="product1">
```

then in js:

```
var product = $("add_to_cart_form").attr("productID");
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm not sure how to link it with each add to cart button.  Basically I want it to say "submit the form linked to the add to cart button that is clicked".  I'm not great with Javascript (learning fast)!

Comment: Add the html you are using to your question and I will try to help some more

Answer (score 0):

Ah...I think I have sorted it.  A little playing around did the trick.

Resulting code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
                $j(document).ready(function () {
                $j('.add_to_cart_form').submit(function() {
                    $j('.add_submit', this).val('Processing...');
                    var url = $j(this).attr('action');
                    var data = $j(this).serialize();
                    $j.post(url, data, function() {$j('.cart-wrap').load('{site_url}cart');
                        $j('.mini-cart').load('{site_url}cart');
                        $j('.add_submit').val('add to cart');
                        $j('.cart-thankyou').slideDown( 500, function() {});
                        $j('.cart-thankyou').delay(1500).slideUp(400);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
            </script>
```